# Удалить нужный элемент массив при помощи кнопки

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии кнопки Destroy, удалялся элемент массива вместе с ключом.

```
let tasks = [];
$('#new').keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    let $this = $(this);
    $('#list').append('<li>\
          <div class="task">\
            <label class="text"><input class="toggle" type="checkbox">' +       $this.val() + '</label>\
              <button class="destroy">Destroy</button>\
          </div>\
     </li>');

   tasks.push($this.val());
   // Очистка Input
   $('#new').val('');
  }
});
$('#list').on('click','button.destroy', function(){
  $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: А как вообще удалить элемент массива с ключом вы знаете?

Comment: Не нужно по кусочкам делать нашими руками Ваш проект. Тут помогают, а не делают за Вас. Реализовать уделание легко можно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для решения этой задачи будут полезны функции:

- [Array.prototype.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)
- [$.closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)
- [$.index](https://api.jquery.com/index/)

```js
let tasks = [];
$('#new').keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    let $this = $(this);
    $('#list').append('<li>\
          <div class="task">\
            <label class="text"><input class="toggle" type="checkbox">' +       $this.val() + '</label>\
              <button class="destroy">Destroy</button>\
          </div>\
     </li>');

   tasks.push($this.val());
   // Очистка Input
   $('#new').val('');
  }
});
$('#list').on('click','button.destroy', function(){
  var $li = $(this).closest('li');
  tasks.splice($li.index(), 1);
  $li.remove();
  console.log(JSON.stringify(tasks));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="new"/>
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

Comment: Угу, если бы я отвечал, то так и сделал бы.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

```
$('#list').on('click','button.destroy', function(){
    let index = $(this).parent().find('label').text();
      if(tasks.indexOf(index) > -1 ){
        tasks.splice(tasks.indexOf(index), 1);
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
      }
      console.debug(tasks); //debug - check U result
    });
```

Comment: А если есть другой элемент с этим же значением?